# EntityFramework CF and Pre-Generate Views

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I want to reduce startup-time by using `Pre-Generate Views` as described on the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx

Can I use `Pre-Generate Views` in `Code First` approach and how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[EF Power Tools CTP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx) contain feature called *Optimize Entity Data Model* which should be equivalent to pre-generating views for EDMX.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not use them in Code First.

Answer (score 0):

looks like Pre-generated views are not supported by Code First (no precompiled queries in EF http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/02/ef-4-1-is-coming-dbcontext-api-amp-code-first-rtw.aspx ). 
Here you can find some performance tips for EF : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx 
You can however reverse your DbContext and extract the EDMX using the [EF Power Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx), once done that you can tune your queries.

Answer (score 0):

EF Power Tools Beta 3 includes pre-generating views for Code First, as you can see at the bottom of this blog post

[EF Power Tools Beta 3 Available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/01/30/ef-power-tools-beta-3-available.aspx)

You can [download this tool from Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)